# How to extract s2p file from a large-signal model? - ADS

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, simulation, model, s-parameters

I am working on a RF IC and I wish to extract s2p file from large-signal model (the large-signal model is available in producer company). How can I do that in ADS?

Comment: This is a design question - more specifically, a question about the use of software tools in the design process. IMHO, the closing was unwarranted.

Comment: I agree, reopened

Comment: I don't see a lot of folk here making answers @VoltageSpike so, maybe it was validly closed in the first place. Of course if SE wants to become the turn-to place for all electronically associated tools then that's a different matter.